# DELETE statement produces INTEGER related error

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, sql-delete

I am trying to delete records from the sessions export table in BigQuery  to create sampled UAT dataset like this:

```
DELETE `xxx.ga_sessions_20161126` 
WHERE NOT(fullVisitorId LIKE '50%' OR fullVisitorId LIKE '75%')
```

Which produces:

> Error: Column trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page has type INT32,
>   which differs from the expected type of INT64

Looks like a bug. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Interesting.  BQ doesn't support INT32 as far as I know.

Comment: It looks like an internal bug

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you are exporting data from Google Analytics to BigQuery, as you have some column data labeled as `trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page`, which is [part of the Google Analytics information](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en). Can you confirm if the table you want to delete was created automatically from a Google Analytics export? If that is correct, maybe you can also add a Google Analytics tag to the question.

Comment: I have added google-analytics tag.

Comment: For some reason, it looks like the Google Analytics export to BigQuery is creating an underlying INT32 data type, while BQ works with INT64. Are you continuously exporting data? If that is not the case, maybe you can try to copy the data to a new table or perform an [export to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) and then re-import it to a new table and see if that way the new tables are created correctly. Then you can delete the old table completely and perform the DELETE statement over the new table with the right schema configuration. Can you consider that option?

Comment: It will make data mocking very difficult. I would prefer it too be fixed in BigQuery or Google Analytics export.  Interestingly it is not a problem for some of the views.

Comment: In order to work more in this issue, you will have to [create a private issue in PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) in order to share some additional information. I will need the project number where the affected tables are created and the table name (which I understand is `xxx.ga_sessions_20161126`, but maybe you are using `xxx` just as an obfuscation, so provide the real name). If you have a GCP support package, feel free to create a case with us and we will be able to assist you further. Once the issue is found, please post the answer here too.